# WPF DataTrigger and button using PRISM

Tags: wpf, prism

I have a question about clarifiying the Data Context in WPF. I have a PRISM based application. I am attempting to put a DataTrigger on a Button control. This Button control is configured to use a PRISM command interpreter.

```
<Button 
   Grid.Column="0"                             
   Content="{Resx AdvancedTroubleShootingButtonLabel}" 
   prism:Click.Command="{Binding AdvancedTroubleShootingCommand}"
 >
   <Button.Resources>
     <Style 
       TargetType="{x:Type Button}"  BasedOn="{StaticResource CDMWrappedButtonStyle}">

       <Style.Triggers>

         <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=SizerVisible, ElementName=SecuritySizer}" Value="False" >
            <Setter Property="Button.IsEnabled" Value="True" />
         </DataTrigger>

         <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=SizerVisible, ElementName=SecuritySizer}" Value="True" >
           <Setter Property="Button.IsEnabled" Value="False" />
         </DataTrigger>
       </Style.Triggers>

     </Style>
   </Button.Resources>
</Button>
```

My assumption was that the DataTriggers would use the specified elementName for the Datacontext of the Trigger. When I test this XAML the trigers do not run. If I remove the PRISM command syntax (and hook into the standard Button click event) and test, then the triggers fire.

What I would like to know is why would the PRISM command handler [syntax] cause the triggers to not use the DataContext identified in the Trigger script?

Comment: Ran into another situation where I was putting binding script on a button. The bound property is a dependency property and should be picked up by the button. It didn't. There is also a PRISM command handler on this button. When I removed it the bound property got caught when it was changed. The interesting thing is that I have another bound property on the same control. It gets caught with the PRISM command binding active. The two bound properties are defined in the ViewModel the View's data Context is attached to. The only difference is the second one uses a converter. Peter

Answer (score 0):

In the command definition, are you setting the CanExecute ?

I might be wrong, but because IsEnabled is bound to CanExecute of its Command, it might prevent the Triggers from working.